# Simular fuente de tráfico para una url concreta

Tags: web, url

Quiero ver la forma en la que puedo emular al ir a una página ej: www.ejemplo.com hacerle creer que llego desde www.mipagina.com les parece eso posible?

Comment: Buen día; la verdad no entiendo tu planteamiento; expon más el escenario y lo que has hecho/tienes hasta este momento. Suerte

Comment: Me refiero sin tocar nada del servidor, sino como usuario poder acceder a una página web y "emular" de algún modo que provengo de un sitio externo que yo elija para que lo tenga en cuenta como tracking sin que sea realmente ese sitio des de el que vengo... espero haberme explicado! Salu2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo sólo si puedes editar directamente el *[HTTP Request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#Request_context)*

Un ejemplo usando CURL

```
$ exec 3>salida.txt
$ exec 4>&1 1>&3
$ curl -H "Host: es.stackoverflow.com" -H "Referer: https://google.com/?q=stack%20overflow%20en%20espa%C3%B1ol" https://stackexchange.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 86632  100 86632    0     0   173k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  173k
$ exec 1>&4 4>&- 3>&-
```

*salida.txt*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/favicon.ico?v=a8def514be8a">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=7739871010e6">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@esStackOverflow" />
    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="es.stackoverflow.com"/>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="uS5zRTpzXl8rRLx9W7Pd7WBcn6-f9FO4KaDi1Tyln_4"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Preguntas y respuestas para programadores y profesionales de la inform&#225;tica"/>

    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=62634cce9d6c" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Preguntas y respuestas para programadores y profesionales de la inform&#225;tica" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://es.stackoverflow.com/"/>
    ...
```

El anterior ejemplo accede a https://stackexchange.com, pero gracias a los headers se especifica que se quiere acceder a la comunidad de stackoverflow en español (virtual host), así mismo le indico al host *stackexchange.com* que se accedió al sitio a través de una referencia del host *google.com* en la localización https://google.com/?q=stack%20overflow%20en%20espa%C3%B1ol